# How to hide query statement while running in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

I have to execute some queries in Firebird, but I need to hide "query source" from viewing in mon$statements or any other log in database.

That's because the query has some business rules that I can't expose to other people.

Is there any way to do it? Or some "trick" that I can use?

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this. However `MON$STATEMENT` only shows your own queries, unless you are `SYSDBA`, the owner of the database, or a user with the `RDB$ADMIN` role (then you can see all queries). Other then `MON$STATEMENT`, there is also the trace facility which allows people with sufficient access to see queries (either on the server or through the service api). People with insufficient access to the database can still see queries if they can see the network traffic between the application and the database server.

The only way is to not give any form of access to the database server to people who should not be able to see the queries. This can be done by hosting the application as a webapplication, or putting a webservice or other form of middleware between the database and the real application.